# How to overlay a form field over an image with a fixed width?

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have a fixed-width image.  Its width adjusts to 100% of screen width.  Its heights adjusts accordingly based on the screen width.

I need to overlay a form field on top of this image.  I still want the full image to appear... all of its width and height as I have it now.

How would I do this?  Also, how could I position the form field to be at a certain location on the image?  It's difficult because the image adjusts based on screen width.  But there's only a portion of the image where the form field fits to look good.  I hope this makes sense.

Here is my current code:

CSS:

```
.fixedimage img{
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="100%">
<div class="fixedimage">
    <center><img src="fixedimage.jpg" /></center>
</div>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

Thank you so much!!

Comment: See my updated answer, does this achieve what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jGzF/4/). You will see an input box overlapping an image.

The important parts are:

```
#formElement 
{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
```

Note `position:absolute` to overlap image and the % positions so that the input moves with the change in the size of the page.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted to know!  Thank you!  I have one follow-up question.  We basically have this image that adjusts to be 100% width and the height then adjusts accordingly.  Therefore, there's no set height in pixels or percentage.  We're trying to fit this form field into a spot of about 300px wide by 200px tall.  It's tough to code it given that the size of the image adjusts based on the screen size.  Is what I'm trying to do impossible with CSS?  I notice that Care.com has it all done perfectly, but I think they're using a different coding language.

Comment: @user3161669 - Glad to help. I am not sure I follow exactly what you are trying to achieve. I would suggest creating a fiddle (it is free to do - just click save afterwards) going as far as you can. Then post a new question referencing the fiddle. You can post the link to the new question as a comment here and I will look, but I am going to have to sign off for a while so it might be a bit later.